# sql update table - statement not working

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, sql-update

I have the below statement in my VBA:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE customer SET Status = 'Premier' WHERE customer_id = 41308408 AND location IN ('London','New York') AND Status = ''"
```

which is meant to update a table called "customer". I can see in my table there are about 20 entries where the customer_id is 41308408 (i.e. if i filter the column for that value), with the location being either London or New York for each entry. The Status column is blank for each of these.

I execute the above code, and it compiles OK, but it says "You are about to update 0 rows". I would be expecting that to be 20, as per above. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's blank and not NULL?

Comment: `Status` is blank or `NULL`? you can check if you WHERE clause is correct by doing a select `SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer_id = 41308408 AND location IN ('London','New York') AND Status = ''`. if no rows are returned change the status check to `status is null`

Comment: thank you all, it is indeed null, and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `status` isn't blank, maybe it's null? Try below solution:

```
UPDATE customer 
SET Status = 'Premier' 
WHERE customer_id = 41308408 
AND location IN ('London','New York') 
AND Status is null
```

Answer (score 0):

The blank is probably a `null` in the database. `Null`s are values - they are the lack thereof. You can't query them with the `=` operator, you need to treat them explicitly with the `is` operator:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE customer SET Status = 'Premier' WHERE customer_id = 41308408 AND location IN ('London','New York') AND Status IS NULL"
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE customer SET Status = 'Premier' WHERE customer_id = 41308408 AND location IN ('London','New York') AND ((Status is null) or length(trim(Status)) = 0)